# Moderncv formatting not appearing when compiled

Tags: templates, moderncv

I recently re-installed MiKTeX and had to re-install moderncv as well, which I did through the Package Manager. I am working on a cover letter file I started before I reinstalled both, and it compiles, but without any of the moderncv formatting (header, personal info, font, paragraph spacing). I don't get any error messages. It just looks like I typed it straight into the editor with no markup. I have no idea what the problem is (and yes, in case you're wondering, I'm still a bit wobbly with LaTeX).

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry} 

\firstname{fab4} 
\familyname{lover} 

\begin{document}



\recipient{}{Company\\Address\\City, Town, Postcode} % Letter recipient
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{Dear Hiring Manager,} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

Insert text here

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\end{document}
```

I'm linking my [logfile](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1caQv0UKjD0AVTcm_cAM0N3hQDVXDki93RW9aofUo0FI/edit?usp=sharing) and a anonymized copy of my [tex file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FNJ1M_dd3dqpLLy1fg_I1ngvnNp6xjseM-6e63e6UM0/edit?usp=sharing) (see above) as google docs because the logfile alone is too long to paste in, and I've no idea where it's gone wrong.

EDIT: I've just tried compiling the CV file and it works perfectly. I think it must be something to do with `\makelettertitle` because when I un-comment it out, I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
 ...                                              
l.74 \makelettertitle
```

A different tex file with the same cover letter format as this one with `\makelettertitle` un-commented also works perfectly. What am I missing?!

Comment: please, put your `.tex` and `.log` files into your questions. It is very inconvenient to collect files from web and also can happen that after while links will not be available anymore. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\recipient{}{Company\\Address\\City, Town, Postcode}` should be `\recipient{Wombat}{Company\\Address\\City, Town, Postcode}`. But as Zarko already said, posting a minimal working example right in this question is the best way to post a question.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the recipient must not be empty.
`\recipient{}{Company\\Address\\City, Town, Postcode}` should be
`\recipient{Wombat}{Company\\Address\\City, Town, Postcode}`.

`Wombat` will be printed in bold face.

It is also possible to use
`\recipient{\normalfont\itshape Wombat}{Company\\Address}` to make it look like the other lines.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).